# Metodo POST no recibe los datos para enviar el correo electrónico

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

He intentado enviar un formulario con AJAX y PHP a un correo electrónico sin embargo no lo he conseguido.

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post" target="_blank" onsubmit='event.preventDefault(); sendForm1("form-contacto")' name="form-contacto">
    <input type="hidden" name="clientRequest" id="clientRequest" value="true" />
    <input type="hidden" name="validDate" id="validDate" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="optin1" id="optin1" value="true" />

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="ffield">
                <label for="firstname">Nombre</label>
                <input type="text" name="nombre-contacto-2" id="firstname" value="" placeholder="Nombre usuario o empresa" required  />
            </div>  
        </div><!-- .col-sm-6 -->
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="ffield">
                <label for="email">* Correo electrónico</label>
                <input type="email" name="email-contacto-2" id="email" value="" placeholder="*Correo electrónico" required />
            </div>                      
        </div><!-- .col-sm-6 -->
    </div><!-- .row -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="ffield">
                <label for="firstname">Telefono</label>
                <input type="text" name="telefono-contacto-2" id="telefono" value="" placeholder="Telefono" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">

                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="comment">Mensaje</label>
                              <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="mensaje"  placeholder="Escribir consulta" name="mensaje-contacto-2" required></textarea>
                            </div>

            </div>

        </div>
```

PHP:

```
 <?php 
 $input = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input") , true);
 $ToEmail = "mi-email@gmail.com"; 
 $EmailSubject = "CONTACTO "; 
 $mailheader="FUE ENVIADO POR".$_POST['nombre-contacto-2']."\n";
 $mailheader .= "From: ".$_POST['email-contacto-2']."\r\n";
 $MESSAGE_BODY = "Nombre: ".$_POST['nombre-contacto-2'].""; 
 $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Telefono: ".$_POST['telefono-contacto-2']."\n"; 
 $MESSAGE_BODY.="MENSAJE".$_POST['mensaje-contacto-2'];
 mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure"); 

 echo "Saved";
 ?>
```

JS:

```
function sendForm1(formName){
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open("POST","send-email-macza-2.php",true);
    http.send(JSON.encodeForm(document.forms[formName]));
    http.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200){
           console.log(http.responseText);
           document.getElementById("envio-exitoso-1").innerHTML="<h1>Datos Enviados Correctamente</h1>";
        }
    }
}
JSON.encodeForm = function(form){
    var array = {};
    for (key in form) {
        var item=form[key];
        if(form.hasOwnProperty(key) && item == "[object HTMLInputElement]"){
            array[item.name]=item.value;
        }
    }
    return JSON.stringify(array);
}
```

Y al enviar solo recibo lo siguiente:

> FUE ENVIADO POR:
>
> From:
>
> Nombre:
>
> Telefono:
>
> MENSAJE

Al parecer las variables quedan en blanco, ¿alguien sabe por qué ocurre?

Comment: Por como procesas el formulario en encodeForm, no se va a enviar el mensaje en sí (el campo mensaje-contacto-2) porque es un `textarea` por lo que no va a ser `[object HTMLInputElement]` sino `[HTMLTextAreaElement]` y se va a ignorar (lo cual te generará errores luego, aunque no debería bloquear el envío del email).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En la parte de PHP que procesa los datos, estas obteniendo todos los valores input a través de la variable **$input** por medio de **file_get_contents()** por lo tanto al momento de hacer la concatenación este mismo debería ser el nombre de la variable y por dentro solo asar el nombre del input HTML que contiene el valor que deseas enviar

```
<?php 
 $input = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input") , true);
 $ToEmail = "mi-email@gmail.com"; 
 $EmailSubject = "CONTACTO "; 
 $mailheader="FUE ENVIADO POR".$input['nombre-contacto-2']."\n";
 $mailheader .= "From: ".$input['email-contacto-2']."\r\n";
 $MESSAGE_BODY = "Nombre: ".$input['nombre-contacto-2'].""; 
  $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Telefono: ".$input['telefono-contacto-2']."\n"; 
 $MESSAGE_BODY.="MENSAJE".$input['mensaje-contacto-2'];
 mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure"); 

 echo "Saved";
```

El error que mencionas de que te aparece no definido es por que seguramente tienes el código javascript en otro archivo y no lo estas invocando, entonces te debería quedar en este orden

```
<form action="" method="post" target="_blank" onsubmit='event.preventDefault(); sendForm1("form-contacto")' name="form-contacto">
    <input type="hidden" name="clientRequest" id="clientRequest" value="true" />
    <input type="hidden" name="validDate" id="validDate" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="optin1" id="optin1" value="true" />

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="ffield">
                <label for="firstname">Nombre</label>
                <input type="text" name="nombre-contacto-2" id="firstname" value="" placeholder="Nombre usuario o empresa" required  />
            </div>  
        </div><!-- .col-sm-6 -->
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="ffield">
                <label for="email">* Correo electrónico</label>
                <input type="email" name="email-contacto-2" id="email" value="" placeholder="*Correo electrónico" required />
            </div>                      
        </div><!-- .col-sm-6 -->
    </div><!-- .row -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="ffield">
                <label for="firstname">Telefono</label>
                <input type="text" name="telefono-contacto-2" id="telefono" value="" placeholder="Telefono" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">

                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="comment">Mensaje</label>
                              <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="mensaje"  placeholder="Escribir consulta" name="mensaje-contacto-2"></textarea>
                            </div>

            </div>

        </div>
        <div id="envio-exitoso-1"></div>
<input type="submit" value="enviar ">
</form>
<script src="funcion.js"></script>
```

Lo siguiente es como debe quedar tu php

```
<?php 
 $input = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input") , true);
 $ToEmail = "correo@hotmail.com"; 
 $EmailSubject = "CONTACTO "; 
 $mailheader="FUE ENVIADO POR".$input['nombre-contacto-2']."\n";
 $mailheader .= "From: ".$input['email-contacto-2']."\r\n";
 $MESSAGE_BODY = "Nombre: ".$input['nombre-contacto-2'].""; 
  $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Telefono: ".$input['telefono-contacto-2']."\n"; 
 $MESSAGE_BODY.="MENSAJE".$input['mensaje-contacto-2'];
 mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure"); 

 echo "Saved";
```

Y tu javascript así

```
function sendForm1(formName){
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open("POST","send.php",true);
    http.send(JSON.encodeForm(document.forms[formName]));
    http.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200){
           console.log(http.responseText);
           document.getElementById("envio-exitoso-1").innerHTML="<h1>Datos Enviados Correctamente</h1>";
        }
    }
}
JSON.encodeForm = function(form){
    var array = {};
    for (key in form) {
        var item=form[key];
        if(form.hasOwnProperty(key) && item == "[object HTMLInputElement]"){
            array[item.name]=item.value;
        }
    }
    return JSON.stringify(array);
}
```

Comment: Me sale que la función sendForm1() no está definida, ¿a qué se puede deber esto?

Comment: @paulzapata ese error que comentas tiene que venir de otro sitio. He probado la solución de Shadow Paz en local y me ha funcionado correctamente.

Comment: checa lo que anexaré a la respuesta para decirte por que te aparece ese error

Comment: ok, estaré al tanto.

Comment: ya quedo en la respuesta asumo que no estabas invocando el archivo javascript dentro del html

Comment: yo puse send.php por que asi nombre el archivo pero ponle el que tu deseas

Comment: lo invoqué desde el head, pero voy a implementarlo como me sugeriste

Comment: me dices si sirvio o no

Comment: le hice cambios al codigo html checa por favor copialo de nuevo, ya me quedo a mi y ya no muestra el error pero vuelve a copiar el html por que le hice cambios @paulzapata

Comment: avisanos sirvio o no

Comment: aún no funciona, incluso antes si se activaba esta instrucción document.getElementById("envio-exitoso-1").innerHTML pero ahora ya no

Comment: checa lo que agrege es que no tienes la etiqueta html del id que requieres esa linea

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75230/discussion-between-shadow-paz-and-paul-zapata).

Answer (score 1):

El error lo tienes en la rutina para serializar el formulario.

No estas iterando correctamente los elementos del formulario, anexo te dejo un ejemplo sencillo de como hacerlo.

```js
JSON.encodeForm = function(form){
 var array = {};
 for (i=0; i<form.elements.length;i++) {
  var item=form.elements[i];
  array[item.name]=item.value;
 }
 return JSON.stringify(array);
}
```