# PHP No recibe los datos enviados por POST

Tags: javascript, php

Estoy haciendo una aplicación simple con PHP y JavaScript. El problema es que, al hacer una petición AJAX a mi servidor PHP, los datos enviados no se reciben en PHP.

Ya intenté con `fetch`, `XMLHttpRequest` y `axios`, pero ninguno de los anteriores funcionó.

Actualmente estoy tratando con `axios`.

JS:

```
axios.post("../api", {
    act:"isLogged"
}).then(e => {
    document.getElementById("services").innerHTML = e.data;
});
```

PHP:

```php
<?php
    print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Sin embargo, el resultado de lo anterior es

```php
Array ( )
```

Intenté esto en un servidor local con XAMPP y al ver que no funcionaba lo subí a un servidor web, pero tampoco funcionó (el resultado fue el mismo).

Comment: cual es el estado de la solicitud??

Comment: @Christian Al hacer `console.log(e)`, se nota que `status` es 200 y el estado es "OK"

Comment: ¿Estas seguro esta ingresando al archivo donde tienes definido el $_POST? y ¿Revisaste que los datos estén en la cabecera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desconozco la razón de esto, pero logré solucionar esto con [`php://`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/wrappers.php.php) (establecido según el manual), tomando como referencia [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/151415/metodo-post-no-recibe-los-datos-para-enviar-el-correo-electr%c3%b3nico/151417#151417) también

```php
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input") , true);
print_r($_POST);
```